# Java Selenium - get the span value

Tags: java, xpath

HTML Tag

```
<span class="slds-pill__label" data-aura-rendered-by="1508:0" xpath="1">jackson</span>
```

I want to get the value `(jackson)` in the above span

I tried the below XPath, but I'm not getting the value

```
//span[@class='slds-pill__label] with geText() its return empty
//span[@class='slds-pill__label] with getAttribute(value) ite return null
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the method name. Have you written getText() or getext() in your code.